# Webserver slow on every 3rd/4th call

Tags: apache, typo3

I'm running a website using Typo3-10.

The page actually works, but on every 3rd or 4th call to the page, it's slow as hell and time to first byte takes up to 10 seconds.
It's intermittently and not bound to a specific page.

Caching is enabled (although most of the content is not cacheable, since it's dynamic content that changes constantly).

There are no errors when the page is loaded (at least, the log is empty [and yes, logging is enabled]).

I have no idea where to start or what to look for…

Comment: Is there some extension plugged into all pages (i.e. via TS)? Without more details it's rather impossible to find the problem. Try to run Admin's panel in FE and display rendering times.

Comment: as the content changes permantly: do you have a racing condition or locking while update data in the background?

Comment: Thanks guys - I'll look into both things. At least, I have an idea to start with now ;)

Comment: I just got a message from my provider saying, that my PHP-Processes are calling an external IPv6-Address on every call. Is there any known T3-Extension that does such a thing?